# How to find python packages correct version for particular python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am having python 2.7 and also python 3.6. For an example i want numpy to be installed in my system.My doubt is like any dependency for python 2.7--numpy(example numpy version 1.0) and python 3.6 --numpy (example numpy version 1.16).Not only for numpy but for all packages.If it is any dependency how i can find that version.

Comment: You can't. Only if you run `pip freeze` on the system it was previously running. Otherwise install the latest version of the package and go backwards if that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependency manager (pip) should take care of this automatically. Just install a package with either

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install numpy
```

`pip` automatically selects the correct version of the module to install and all subdependencies.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for sharing this. It is more helpful